# Textarea value not retaining line breaks from variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a textarea that needs to retain the submitted value and format after submission, but for some reason \n does not seem to get passed from the variable php variable.

```
$text = '1\n2\n3';

echo '<script>
var text = "'.$text.'";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>'
```

The variable is passed from php to JS. When I echo the variable I get the expected result:

```
1\n2\n3
```

When the variable is assigned to the textarea value the result is:

```
123
```

Instead of:

```
1
2
3
```

Now if I change the js to the following I get the expected result with each number on a new line.

```
$("textarea").val("1\n2\n3");
```

Does anyone know why the php variable is not passing the \n returns to JS?

Comment: In PHP backslesh "\" has role to block something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json encode should escape your line breaks in a way JS will understand.

```
$text = json_encode('1\n2\n3');

echo '<script>
var text = JSON.parse("'.$text.'");
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>'
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone who provided a suggested solution, unfortunately none of these answers worked when passing a session variable. But this gave me an idea for simple hack even though it's not very clean. I passed the json_ecoded session variable and then passed the variable through `substr($text, 1,-1)` to remove the starting & ending quotes so it could be parsed by JS. For some reason JSON.parse was not working as intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.

```
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>


<?php

$text = '1\n2\n3';

echo '<script>
var text = "'.$text.'";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>'
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are expecting Browser Javascript to understand PHP's "\n" character. That will not work. Also, your code uses the single quote to denote the newline character. PHP requires that you use double quotes to denote the newline special character.

There are at least two ways you can fix this.

The first is to use PHP's nl2br() function. In that case, your code could be rewritten as:

```
$text = "1\n2\n3"; //notice the use of double quotes.

echo '<script>
var text = "'. nl2br($text).'";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>'
```

A second way is to use the HTML 
 tag directly in your variable declaration. This would obviate the need to use PHP's nl2br() function.

```
$text = '1<br>n2<br>n3';

echo '<script>
var text = "'.$text.'";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>'
```

Either of both approaches should work.

Comment: Thanks I do use nl2br for that variable in another part of the function, but I don't believe the textarea can parse <br> tags because when I did try that it displayed <br> as text. So I'm currently reverting the <br> tags back to \n with strreplace: `$text = str_replace('<br />','\n',$text);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '1\n2\n3';
```

change to double quote sign:

```
$text = "1\n2\n3";
```

In PHP double quote " and single quote ' not parse equal. For something we need use double quote, like this.

For:
$text = "\n1\n2\n3\n";

Source Page view would be:

```
<script>
var text = "
1
2
3
";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").attr("placeholder","1) Start Each Comment On A New Line...");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});

</script>
```